# How to make a well integrated sidebar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, sidebar

I'm using a sidebar into my android app, this app required to run on from 7' to 10' android tablets, the problem is the side bar gives me different behaviors with the different sizes, look at the following pics:

**with 10':**

[image]

**with 7':**

[image]

and that happens with either fixing the sidebar size, making it in a specific range, or giving it the freedom to fit.

**My code:**

```
                         <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/bottom_of_center"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                            android:layout_weight="3"
                            android:orientation="vertical" >

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:text="Dimming Control"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                android:layout_gravity="left"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

                            <LinearLayout  
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:layout_width="400dp"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:layout_weight="2"
                                android:layout_gravity="left"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                                android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                                android:paddingRight="1dp"
                                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:background="@drawable/light_dimmingbg">


                            <SeekBar
                                android:id="@+id/seekbar"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="left"
                                android:layout_weight="2"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                                android:max="100"
                                android:minHeight="10dp"
                                android:maxHeight="13dp"
                                android:minWidth="120dp"
                                android:progress="20"
                                android:thumb="@drawable/light_sliderhandle"
                                />
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use nine-patch images and different images for different screen resolution for the similar look n feel

Comment: @SuhailMehtin  there are many devices the range between 7 and 10 inches so it's not logical to add that much of images for every single image

Comment: 7 inc screen will come under your large-layout and 10 inc will come under xlarge-layout.Define different layout for them and user nine-patch images instead.

Comment: @SuhailMehta also i'm not using specific images but thumb, the progress bar is the default one adn the layout is a gradient color